# Error: Unexpected Array reference at (1) (compiler g95 -std=F)

Tags: arrays, fortran

I made a roll dice program for a university project. When programing and compiling on my pc (macbook) no problems, then I move everything on university server (ubuntu 12) and added a plot module without changing anything in the "rolling" code. Now compiler gives me this error:

```
In file 000_Dados.f95:61

     dados(j)=int(rnum(j)*6 + 1)
                    1
Error: Unexpected array reference at (1)
```

My code is the following (i've emphasized the error line):

```
program dice

use graph
use mcf_tipos

real(kind=doble), dimension(1:5)                  :: rnum          !! random number
integer(kind=int), dimension(1:5)                 :: dados         !! dices
integer(kind=int), dimension(0:5)                 :: count        !!
real(kind=doble), dimension(0:5)                  :: prob
integer(kind=int)                                 :: ax, n, i, j, k, l, m

!plot variables

character(len=132), dimension (1:6)     :: datafile
integer, dimension(1:6)                 :: x,y,tipo
character(len=132), dimension(1:3)      :: alabel

!open datafiles

open(unit=0,file="0ax.dat", status="replace", action="readwrite")
open(unit=1,file="1ax.dat", status="replace", action="readwrite")
open(unit=2,file="2ax.dat", status="replace", action="readwrite")
open(unit=3,file="3ax.dat", status="replace", action="readwrite")
open(unit=4,file="4ax.dat", status="replace", action="readwrite")
open(unit=5,file="5ax.dat", status="replace", action="readwrite")

!inizialize variables

forall (l=0:5)
count(l)=0
prob(l)=0
end forall

!first null data line

write (unit=0, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), 0, prob(0)
write (unit=1, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), 0, prob(1)
write (unit=2, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), 0, prob(2)
write (unit=3, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), 0, prob(3)
write (unit=4, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), 0, prob(4)
write (unit=5, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), 0, prob(5)

!!! THE PROGRAM BEGINS !!!

print *, "¿cuantos tiros?"
read *, n



do i=1,n
    call random_number(rnum)
    ax=0

    !!Roll dices!!

    do j=1,5

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!HERE'S THE ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        dados(j)=int(rnum(j)*6 + 1)
        if (dados(j)==1) then
        ax=ax+1         !!AX Count
        endif
    end do

    !! Count to Probability

    select case(ax)
    case(0)
        count(0)=count(0)+1
        prob(0)=real(count(0))/i
    case(1)
        count(1)=count(1)+1
        prob(1)=real(count(1))/i
    case(2)
        count(2)=count(2)+1
        prob(2)=real(count(2))/i
    case(3)
        count(3)=count(3)+1
        prob(3)=real(count(3))/i
    case(4)
        count(4)=count(4)+1
        prob(4)=real(count(4))/i
    case(5)
        count(5)=count(5)+1
        prob(5)=real(count(5))/i
    end select

    !! write data !!

    write (unit=0, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), i, prob(0)
    write (unit=1, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), i, prob(1)
    write (unit=2, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), i, prob(2)
    write (unit=3, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), i, prob(3)
    write (unit=4, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), i, prob(4)
    write (unit=5, fmt="(i8, t10, f10.6)"), i, prob(5)

end do

do k=0,5
print *, "La probabilidad que salgan ", k,  " ases entre 5 dados es ", prob(k)*100, "%"
end do

!!CLOSE DATA FILES!!

close(unit=0)
close(unit=1)
close(unit=2)
close(unit=3)
close(unit=4)
close(unit=5)

!!PLOT OPTIONS!!

datafile(1)="0ax.dat"
datafile(2)="1ax.dat"
datafile(3)="2ax.dat"
datafile(4)="3ax.dat"
datafile(5)="4ax.dat"
datafile(6)="5ax.dat"

forall (m=1:5)
x(m)=1
y(m)=2
tipo(m)=1
end forall

alabel(1)="n tiros"
alabel(2)="probabilidad"

!!PLOT!!

call plot(datafile,x,y,axeslabel=alabel,type=tipo)

end program dice
```

Comment: Are you sure you pasted right code: `kind=doble` ?

Comment: @Peter: sounds like spanish, probably defined inside `mcf_tipos`.

Comment: Yep! I'm studying in the basque country ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `doble` and `int` as kinds, so they are probably integer parameters declared in one of those modules you include. Because `int` is now an integer parameter, it overrides the `int` intrinsic function.

So, go look into graph/mcf_tipos source code and get rid of the `int` assignment, change it to e.g. `my_int_kind`.

It might be a good idea to use e.g. `iso_fortran_env` instead, then you have kind parameters that give you specific sizes, e.g.:

```
use iso_fortran_env

real(real64) :: rnum(5)
integer(int32) :: dados(5)
```

and then get rid of your own defined kinds.

Comment: Thank you!! I just change the kind int to reg_int in the kind module and it compiles ;) I'm not changing the kind module cause it's made by the professor, even if he made this mistake :p